# gunicorn doesn't process simultaneous requests concurrently

Tags: asynchronous, gunicorn, worker

I am trying to serve long running requests using gunicorn and its async workers but I can't find any examples that I can get to work. I used the example [here](http://gunicorn.org/) but tweaked to add a fake delay (sleep for 5s) before returning the response:

```
def app(environ, start_response):
    data = "Hello, World!\n"
    start_response("200 OK", [
        ("Content-Type", "text/plain"),
        ("Content-Length", str(len(data)))
    ])
    time.sleep(5)
    return iter([data])
```

Then I run gunicorn so:

`gunicorn -w 4 myapp:app -k gevent`

When I open up two browser tabs and type in `http://127.0.0.1:8000/` in both of them and send the requests almost at the same time, the requests appear to get processed **sequentially** - one returns after 5 seconds and the other returns after a **further** 5 seconds.

Q. I am guessing the sleep isn't gevent friendly? But there are 4 workers and so even if the type of worker was 'sync' two workers should handle two requests simultaneously?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I just ran into the same thing, opened a question here: [Requests not being distributed across gunicorn workers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23038678/requests-not-being-distributed-across-gunicorn-workers) . The result is, it appears that the browser serializes access to the same page. I'm guessing perhaps this has something to do w/ cacheability, i.e. the browser thinks it's likely the page is cacheable, wait until it loads finds out it isn't so it makes another request and so on.

Comment: Thanks @CrazyCasta. I have verified your answer by installing another browser and sending requests from two separate browsers (chromium and firefox) simultaneously, and the requests do get serviced in parallel.

Comment: OMFG...this was drying me insane....was like...why is threading not working...thank you! just did: localhost:8000/?a=1 and localhost:8000/?b=1 and of course it works

Answer (score 1):

Give `gevent.sleep` a shot instead of `time.sleep`.

It's weird that this is happening with `-w 4`, but `-k gevent` is an async worker type, so it's possible gunicorn is feeding both requests to the same client. Assuming that's what's happening, `time.sleep` will lock your process unless you use `gevent.monkey.patch_all()`.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>When using gunicorn with non-blocking worker type, like gevent, It will use ONLY ONE process dealing with requests, so it's no surprise that your 5-second work carried out sequentially.</strike>

The async worker is useful when your workload is light, and request rate is rapid, in that case, gunicorn can utilize times wasted on waiting IO (like, waiting for socket to be writable to write the response to it), <strike>by switching to another worker to work another request.</strike> by switching to another request assigned to the same worker.

**UPDATE**

I was wrong.

When using gunicorn with non-blocking worker type, with worker settings in gunicorn, each worker is a process, that runs a separate queue.

So if the `time.sleep` was ran on different process, it will run simultaneously, but when it's ran in the same worker, it will be carried out sequentially.

The problem is that the gunicorn loadbalancer may not have distributed the two requests into two worker processes. You can check the current process by `os.getpid()`.

Comment: Gunicorn does not use only one process to handle requests; it uses the number you specify as the `-w` flag.

Comment: @ron.rothman That's true! My explanation is wrong, thanks for mentioning.